# Nodemailer gives error for incorrect user and password

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

Im using nodemailer for a email from a registration form.

Here is my form

```
           <form action="/registration" method="post">
                <h3 class="text-center" style="font-family: 'champagne-limo';">Registration</h3>
                <div class="long-border mb-4"></div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <input class="form-control" style="font-family: 'champagne-limo';" type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email">  
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <input class="form-control" style="font-family: 'champagne-limo';" type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <input class="form-control" style="font-family: 'champagne-limo';" type="password" placeholder="Re-Enter Password" required>    
                </div>
                <input class="create-accnt col-2" type="submit">
            </form>`enter code here`
```

And in my app.js I have this

```
app.get("/registration", function(req,res){
res.render("registration.ejs")
});

app.post("/registration", function(req,res){
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'yahoo',
    auth: {
      user: 'test@yahoo.com',
      pass: 'Test123'
    }
});

var mailOptions = {
from: 'Tester ✔ <test@gmail.com>',
to: 'test@gmail.com',
subject: 'Testing test ✔',
text: 'It works! ✔',  //plaintext body
html: '<p>It works</p>'//rich text html body
};

//send mail with defined transport object
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
     if(error){
     console.log(error);
     }else{
    console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
}
});
})
```

When I hit submit in my console I get an error with my own mail client. Then I created a test email on yahoo and get the same error. And I missing something? This looks like exactly how the instruction on the documentation put it together.

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

where you found the "service" options?

check the current nodemailer transport options [here](https://nodemailer.com/smtp/)

you need to set the host and port options.

Comment: Actually there IS the option `service` for well-known mail services. http://nodemailer.com/smtp/well-known/

Answer (score 0):

Sample code - Nodemailer with Yahoo:

```
const yahoo_host = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com";
const email_smtp = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: yahoo_host,
  auth: {
    user: "someone@yahoo.com",
    pass: "PASSWORD_HERE"
  }
});
```